# Re render Angular Component Periodically

Tags: javascript, angular, rendering, angular2-changedetection

I'm facing an issue with updating the relative time that is being shown.

I have a field let's say `created_at` which I put it through a pipe that gives me result as **Just Now**, **1 minute ago**, etc.

The code looks something like this

```
<div>{{ created_at | conversationTime }}</div>
```

Now, I want to update these values every minute, so I do

```
setPeriodicRefresh(minutes) {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }, 1 * 1000 * 60);
  }
```

But the problem with this is angular change detection works if there is any data changed, and in this case my data i.e. `created_at` is not changed, but the value I generate with it by the pipe.

Can anyone help me how do I go through this?

Comment: Move this logic to components. it should work as expected

Comment: You mean do something like <div>getConversationTime(created_at)</div>
Wouldn't this make this method call a ton of times?

Comment: why not just return this value from function.

Comment: you call getConversationTime(created_at) from component. Assign the date time to public property, which will be displayed in template.

Answer (score 0):

As you say angular will not rerender your pipe because it's memoizing the result.

As a default angular makes all pipes "pure" which mean they are idempotent.

By changing the pipe to be a `pure: false` pipe it will run on each go.

```
@Pipe({
  ...
  pure: false
})
```

https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-and-impure-pipes

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the value of any property changes in a component angular change detection works e.g

component.ts

```
time = 0;

ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.time++;
    }, 1000)
}
```

component.html

```
<div>{{time}}</div>
```